# How can I set the mobile player movement type to DPAD in Roblox Studio?

Tags: mobile, lua, roblox

I am currently creating a game that requires players to be in shift lock and their character will move when they look around. However, when mobile players play, if they use the dynamic thumb stick or any other thumb stick other than DPAD they will be moved around just moving the joystick around.

I experimented and found that DPAD works just fine for Mobile and eliminates that issue, however Im not sure how to/if i can force that on mobile players that join.

I've tried scripting it, looking up youtube videos, searching online, and even trying to get chatgpt but there doesnt seem to be much content regarding mobile movement type.

Answer (score 0):

https://create.roblox.com/docs/input/mobile

See the Movement Modes section of that link. It says that you can use  StarterPlayer.DevTouchMovementMode to set what way the player moves (Thumbstick, Tap to Move, DPad, etc) when they join. This also prevents them from changing the movement type to something else if it is not set to UserChoice.

However, it does also say in the documentation that **DPad was removed from the app** and that it should not be used. If you really really need it though for whatever reason, that's how- just set StarterPlayer (a service you can find next to StarterPack in the Explorer) .DevTouchMovementMode to DPad (Enum.DevTouchMovementMode.DPad).

Note: It's possible that the DPad option won't appear in the dropdown in the Properties window since it was removed. If this is the case, open the command bar/line and run this command:

```
game.StarterPlayer.DevTouchMovementMode = Enum.DevTouchMovementMode.DPad
```

If you need help with this, just ask. (I did not test this solution in Studio though, so it isn't guranteed to work especially since DPad isn't meant to be used anymore supposedly. You should find a better solution to your problem that isn't a removed feature if you haven't already.)